# open iframe and collapse entire page

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, iframe

After the user submits a form I want an iframe to open and cover the full screen. The normal content would collapse so only the iframed content is seen. how is this done. Simply opening the iframe will leave all the content above it and below it.

```
<div id="iWait" style="display:none;"><center><iframe src="http://website.com" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe></center></div>
```

Comment: why don't you actually navigate to your `website.com`?

Comment: because the website is processing the form in the background, hence the iframe is needed

Comment: so what happens when the processing is done ?

Comment: @MajidLAISSI I am with you this makes no sense to me......

Answer (score 1):

Note that defining an iframe in the code will cause it to load in the background.  This can unnecessarily slow down the page if it needn't be loaded until later.

Start with HTML like this (note the `fixed` positioning):

```
<iframe id="preventBoredom" src="http://www.domain.com/" frameborder="0" style="position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; z-index: 1000; display: none;"></iframe>
```

Then, reveal it with `.show()` like this:

```
$('#preventBoredom').show();
```

If you only want to load the iframe when it's revealed, set the initial iframe `src` to a blank HTML page, and use this jQuery instead:

```
$('#preventBoredom').src('http://www.domain.com/').show();
```

---

**Note in reply to @ROY_Finley and for @Mort_Goldman:** I'm having trouble imagining a good situation for using this, unless you intend to hide the iframe again at some point.  For example, you might want something to keep the user busy while an airline search result set is loading (these usually take a while to load).  But this method makes the user think they're on another site -- and they'd be annoyed if the window suddenly were nuked.

If the form processing is a slow server task, you should have the processing script close output before proceeding with processing.  This will allow the server to finish its work in the background while the browser goes on it's merry way.

Comment: Why would anyone want to do this? This is not a negative comment against your answer, but for the life of me, I cannot think of a single reason to open an iframe while a form is posting. Maybe you could shed some light on this?